# undefined JSON values in Javascript error

Tags: javascript, json

I am reading through a JSON object, trying to loop through the text and create substrings of the text. It is, for some reason coming back as "cannot read property 'roles' of undefined." What am I missing?

```
  // target language text
var text1 =  obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].text;

var strArry1 = [];  
var colorArr1 = ["DarkSalmon", "ForestGreen", "Brown"];
for(var t=0; t<obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles.length; t++)
             {
// create variables representing substrings of the Source language Sentence
var tgt1 = text1.substring((obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset - obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset),(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset - 1));
var tgt2 = text1.substring(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset,obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].endOffset);
var tgt3 =
text1.substring(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].endOffset,obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].text.length);

strArry.push('<h4>'+tgt1+'</h4>');
strArry.push('<h4>'+'<font color="'+colorArr1[i]+'">"'+tgt2+'</font>'+'</h4>');

if(i == obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles[0].length-1)
                {
                    strArry.push('<h4>'+tgt3+'</h4>');
                }

                 text1 =  s3;
             }
```

Please see the JSON object in reference below:

```
[
  {
    "description": "",
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "thing commented on"
      },
      {
        "name": "commentor"
      }
    ],
    "srcLanguageSentence": {
      "roles": [
        {
          "beginOffset": 23,
          "endOffset": 30,
          "name": "thing commented on",
          "text": "on them"
        },
        {
          "beginOffset": 5,
          "endOffset": 7,
          "name": "commentor",
          "text": "We"
        }
      ],
      "text": "  `` We wo n't comment on them . '' ",
      "verb": {
        "beginOffset": 15,
        "endOffset": 22,
        "text": "comment"
      }
    },
    "tgtLanguageSentences": [
      {
        "roles": [
          {
            "beginOffset": 1,
            "endOffset": 31,
            "name": "thing commented on",
            "text": "Weitere Aspekte der Kommission"
          },
          {
            "beginOffset": 44,
            "endOffset": 47,
            "name": "commentor",
            "text": "ich"
          },
          {
            "beginOffset": 48,
            "endOffset": 55,
            "name": "negation",
            "text": "nicht ."
          }
        ],
        "text": "  Weitere Aspekte der Kommission kommentiere ich nicht . ",
        "verb": {
          "beginOffset": -1,
          "endOffset": -1,
          "sense": "COMMENT, intransitive",
          "text": "kommentieren"
        }
      }
    ],
    "verb": "KOMMENTIEREN"
  }
]
```

Comment: Cannot read property `roles` of `undefined` **at what line and position**?

Comment: `tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t]`? You're SURE you need to use the exact same index for both arrays? That's... unusual...

Comment: Seems to me that it's suppose to be `obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles[t]`. Just guessing based on the for loop going for the length of `obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles`.

Comment: @DevinH. That's correct, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your references to

`obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t]`

to

`obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles[t]`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the attached JSON object is just a snippet. That is the first of a set of hundreds of objects within the JSON file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem:
In below snippet code you are looping through the role but in substring you passing obj[t].
As per above given JSON you have only one item in obj however in role you have more than 1 item.

```
for(var t=0; t<obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles.length; t++)
             {
// create variables representing substrings of the Source language Sentence
var tgt1 = text1.substring((obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset - obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset),(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset - 1));
var tgt2 = text1.substring(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset,obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].endOffset);
var tgt3 =
text1.substring(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].endOffset,obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].text.length);
```

**Answere is:**

```
var tgt1 = text1.substring((obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles[t].beginOffset - obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles[t].beginOffset),(obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles[t].beginOffset - 1));
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to know, from debugging, which line is throwing the error. But it's probably this one:

```
var tgt1 = text1.substring((obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset - obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset),(obj[t].tgtLanguageSentences[t].roles[t].beginOffset - 1));
```

Using `t` to index `obj` and `tgtLAnguageSentences` and `roles` is problematic based on your JSON object example.  The loop will run 4 times based on `t<obj[0].tgtLanguageSentences[0].roles.length`.

When t = 1, for instance, you are trying to find a value at `obj[1].tgtLanguageSentences[1].roles[1]` if there is no object at obj[1].tgtLanguageSentences[1] then you will get "cannot read property 'roles' of undefined."

Comment: I forgot to mention that the attached JSON object is just a snippet. That is the first of a set of hundreds of objects within the JSON file. Any thoughts?

Comment: You've got three answers and some comments all pointing to the same thing, it this is not the problem you will need to look at which line is throwing the error in the debugger.